# A better way to handle input in lit component

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, web-component, lit-element, lit

I am looking for a better way to handle all inputs in my lit component. I want to use less code. I am also using Typescript. I am using `@change=${this.handleInput}` for all my inputs. Here is a code how this function looks like:

```
  handleInput(e: Event) {
    const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

    switch(input.id){
      case 'title':
        this.title = input.value 
        break;
      case 'description':
        this.description = input.value 
        break;
        case 'startDate':
          this.startDate = input.value 
          break;
        case 'endDate':
          this.endDate = input.value 
          break;
        case 'startTime':
          this.startTime = input.value 
          break;
        case 'endTime':
          this.endTime = input.value 
          break;
      default:
        return
    }
  }
```

This is reactive properties:

```
@property() title: string 
@property() description: string 
@property() startDate: string
@property() endDate: string
@property() startTime: string
@property() endTime: string
```

This is a html that renders in the component:

```
  <form>
        <h2>Add</h2>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>*Information</legend>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="courseTitle">*Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" @change=${this.handleInput} required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label>*Description </label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="description" @change=${this.handleInput}></textarea>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>*Date</legend>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label>Start</label>
              <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" @change=${this.handleInput} required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label>End</label>
              <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" @change=${this.handleInput} required />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <legend>*Time</legend>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label>Start</label>
            <input type="time" id="startTime" name="startTime" @change=${this.handleInput} required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label>End</label>
            <input type="time" id="endTime" name="endTime" @change=${this.handleInput} required />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: This pattern is highly dependent on very consistent handling of the input values. Right now they're all strings with no validation or conversion. As soon as you need to do anything custom per input - like converting the date fields to real Dates - things will get more complicated.

I would recommend using separate handler methods. It's more code but more straightforward, type-safe, and customizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *switching* your `switch` statement for:

```js
handleInput( evt ) {
  let { id , value } = evt.target;
  this[ id ] = value;
}
```

Comment: I get this error:  TS2488: Type 'EventTarget | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: That is the TypeScript compiler; I posted native JS code. You have to apply TS yourself

Comment: It should be `const {id, value} = evt.target;`. Object destructuring with curly braces rather than square brackets. TS error is due to `evt.target` not being an iterable, therefore, can't destructure with square brackets. You may need to do some type assertions to get TS to be okay with `this[id] = value;` as well.

Comment: Good catch!  didn't try code beforehand